# Disabling MMS on Twilio

Tags: python, twilio

Is there a way to disable MMS on a number from Twilio? I only see articles on disabling SMS entirely, and I want to disable MMS as there are additional charges and is not being used.

Comment: Are you talking about disabling incoming or outgoing MMS?

Comment: incoming MMS mainly, but preferably both

Comment: Are you finding people are sending media messages to your number? There's only an additional charge if you are being sent media or using the number to send media.

Comment: yes, people have been sending media messages to my number, which is why I would like to find a way to disable mms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to purchase a phone number that is not MMS compatible.

Comment: That's what it seems like :(

Comment: If you are partial to a specific number that has MMS enabled, you could consider checking the MediaContentType and/or the MediaUrl parameters. If they are anything other than a plain text message, you can respond with a Reject verb. That would prevent any charges to your account.

Comment: how do you purchase such number? When i search on twilio for a number and check 'SMS' compatible, I can't find one that does not have mms...